# EVP_PKEY_verify doesn't work when using EC_KEY

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

`EVP_PKEY_verify()` in most cases fails if EVP_PKEY structure contains EC key, but in some cases it succeed.

openssl documentation about `EVP_PKEY_verify()` shows only example with rsa key. But I can't find any example of verification when the EVP_PKEY contains an EC key

```
    auto evp = EVP_PKEY_new();
    auto eckey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
    assert(1 == EC_KEY_generate_key(eckey));
    assert(1 == EC_KEY_check_key(eckey));
    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_assign_EC_KEY(evp, eckey));

    vector<unsigned char> msg = { 'a', 'd', 'f', 'h', 'k' };

    const int sha256Len = 32;
    unsigned char sha[sha256Len];

    SHA256(&(msg[0]), msg.size(), sha);

    //----signing
    auto evpctx=EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(evp, nullptr);

    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_sign_init(evpctx));

    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(evpctx, EVP_sha256()));

    size_t signLen = 0;
    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_sign(evpctx, NULL, &signLen, sha, sha256Len));

    vector<unsigned char> sig(signLen);

    auto ret = EVP_PKEY_sign(evpctx, &(sig[0]), &signLen, sha, sha256Len);

    assert(ret == 1);

    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(evpctx);

    ///-----veryfication

    auto evpctx1 = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(evp, nullptr);

    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_verify_init(evpctx1));

    assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_signature_md(evpctx1, EVP_sha256()));

    ret = EVP_PKEY_verify(evpctx1, &sig[0], sig.size(), sha, sha256Len);

    EVP_PKEY_free(evp);
    EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(evpctx1);
    assert(ret == 1);
```

The above code, when run in a loop, fails most of times, but not always. Some iterations succeed.
If I generate an RSA key instead of an EC key and put it into EVP_PKEY, then it is ok. What I am doing wrong?
Can you give me a working example of using `EVP_PKEY_verify()` with an ec key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is as follows:

Here, you determine the maximum size of the signature output buffer:

```
assert(1 == EVP_PKEY_sign(evpctx, NULL, &signLen, sha, sha256Len));
```

and here you allocate this buffer:

```
vector<unsigned char> sig(signLen);
```

This is correct. But you have to be aware, that this is only the *maximum* needed size. The size, which is indeed *used* can be *less*!

So in this line

```
auto ret = EVP_PKEY_sign(evpctx, &(sig[0]), &signLen, sha, sha256Len);
```

the *actually* used output buffer size is written to `signLen`, which you have to specify here

```
ret = EVP_PKEY_verify(evpctx1, &sig[0], signLen, sha, sha256Len);
```

when you verify the signature! With this small modification your code should work as expected.

Comment: great, thany you